# Is there any reason not to dynamically load a website content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Now that (V8)Chrome and (SpiderMonkey)Firefox's JS Dom traversals are relatively fast : Is there any reason not to dynamically load in website content via javascript?

I was thinking of requesting large files (images and such) with Javascript while displaying a loading bar. Is there any reason not to dynamically load the large JS/JPG files?

I don't see it very often and wanted to make such it was not a big mistake.

Comment: JavaScript disabled browser.

Comment: Thats true, but I have gotten to the point where I just display a "Javascript required to view this page" anyway.

Comment: Not quite clear your purpose on this question.

Comment: Search engines don't load dynamic content, so it's the **absolute worst** thing you can do for SEO. Subsequently, your described method doesn't provide any benefits, so there is no reason not to load content normally.

Comment: If your page loads slowly enough that you need a loading bar then it's too slow.

Comment: No, I think you need to be carefully about SEO. Remember that the dynamic content will not be crawled by bots. There are now too many solutions and practices to avoid this. Just take it in mind.

Comment: @ChristianVarga is not so bad today, you have great solutions (as http://prerender.io) to avoid this problematic.

Comment: @ianaya89 & Christian Varga I guess I didn't think that through before writing the post : I was planing on only loading in images and JS files to avoid this issue.

Comment: @nnnnnn Having the total website size under 2mb is a must IMHO : On most internet connections that will load in <1-6 seconds... But for mobile connections you can often get into 6-10 second loading times, and at that point I like to have a loading bar.

Answer (score 1):

That depends if it's client sided or server sided with something like node.js.

If it's client sided, depending on how many two way request calls are made at the same time, it can use alot of RAM on the visitor's computer.

Your basically offloading alot of the image/data/stream processing to the user's computer/tablet/phone vs the server.

Comment: From what I have tested, with node.js I have even seen no performance impact... But Client sided with `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML` calls really hurt load times

Comment: I don't understand the distinction this answer tries to make. In a traditional Web page the html specifies image sources and the browser loads them. The OP is talking about having JS load the images, which again results in the browser requesting them. How does that offload processing from the server to the client?

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried specifically about images, there are many methods around deferring the loading until the images are required. You can avoid loading the source until the image is in view. For example, use a tiny transparent image as the source, and store the real source in a data attribute:

```
<img src='data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==' data-src='/path/to/real/image.jpg' />
```

Then use the jQuery inview plugin to load the image when it appears on the screen: https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview

```
$('img').on('inview', function(e, isInView) {
  if ( ! isInView ) return;

  $(this)
    .unbind('inview')
    .attr( 'src', $(this).data('src') );
});
```

I don't know why you would want to defer the javascript; if you've got hundreds of kilobytes of javascript files then you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Another is latency. We're used to being able to ping the other side of the world and receive a response quite quickly. I get a ping response from SO on avg in 600ms.

```
C:\Users\enhzflep>ping www.stackoverflow.com

Pinging stackoverflow.com [198.252.206.140] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 198.252.206.140: bytes=32 time=809ms TTL=38
Reply from 198.252.206.140: bytes=32 time=501ms TTL=38
Reply from 198.252.206.140: bytes=32 time=493ms TTL=38
Reply from 198.252.206.140: bytes=32 time=630ms TTL=36
```

With satelite connections, you're looking at over a second - this means you want to batch-up your requests as much as possible. Even if the page was 200 bytes, and the AJAX content 200 bytes, you're going to be looking at a page-load time of over 2 seconds. Sound like much fun to surf?

Comment: This is a very good point, it sounds like a dynamic page approach would work much better in a NODE.JS environment.